# Using .on to trap submit on dynamically loaded form

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a form that I load into a popover via ajax. The form is defined like:

```
<form id="generate_form" class="form" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/tokens/create" method="POST">
```

I wanted to trap the form submit, and submit the data using AJAX instead.  So I added the following script:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(this).on('submit','#generate-form', function (e) {
      alert('trapped?');
      return false;
    });
  });
```

However, when I try this, the form event is not trapped, i.e. I never see the alert dialogue.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console? you have several syntax problems in the above code.

Comment: Problem with my copy and pasting/simplying skills.  Actually code has correct syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misspelled `"#generate-form"` (underscore instead of dash) and forgot some parenthesis:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(this).on('submit', '#generate_form', function (e) {
        alert('trapped?');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You code is probably breaking because of 2 missing closing parentheses

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(this).on('submit','#generate_form', function (e) {
      alert('trapped?');
      return false;
    }); // <-- added closing parentheses
  }); // <-- added closing parentheses
```

Comment: I had that correct in my actual code, just missed them when I removed some of the code I had.  Turns out to be mispelling as Mario pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

Almost.. :{D

```
$('#generate_form').on('submit', function(e) {

    alert('trapped?');

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

I would also recommend checking out [jQuery's `.on()` Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) - there are a lot of useful examples on there.

Comment: If this works, why wouldn't his own code work? He is using correct syntax other than typos like missed `)` in two places.

Comment: Noticed that when I reread the on() documentation. The answer is that he missed a closing paren.